# Problema de inicialização de aplicação NodeJS em Hospedagem UOL

Tags: node.js, express.js, hospedagem

Galera,

Eu estou com minha aplicação funcionando 100% na minha máquina local, porém quando eu faço upload dos arquivos para a minha hospedagem Node na UOL HOST ela não funciona na inicialização.
Estou usando a mesma versão do node da UOL (4.4.5).

O erro que apresenta no **nodejs.log** é:

```
module.js:341
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'express'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/web/webapps/server.js:14:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
{ [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
events.js:154
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8080
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:893:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:916:20)
    at Server.__dirname.Server.Server._listen2 (net.js:1246:14)
    at listen (net.js:1282:10)
    at Server.__dirname.Server.Server.listen (net.js:1378:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/web/webapps/server.js:76:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
    at startup (node.js:148:18)
    at node.js:405:3
{ [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
events.js:154
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
```

Meu **package.json** está assim:

```
{
  "name": "pokestop",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "author": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.0.2",
    "colors": "^0.6.2",
    "express": "~4.7.2",
    "mongoose": "~3.8.14",
    "slug": "^0.9.1",
    "morgan": "~1.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "~3.6.2",
    "gulp-concat": "~2.2.0",
    "gulp-filter": "~0.4.1",
    "gulp-minify-css": "~0.3.7",
    "gulp-minify-html": "~0.1.4",
    "gulp-rename": "~1.2.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "~0.3.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.10.0"
  }
}
```

E meu **server.js** está assim:

```
'use strict';

var express  = require('express');
var database = require('./server/config/database');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var http = require('http');
var colours = require('colors');
var logger   = require('morgan');
var allowCors = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  //res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');

    next();
};

require('colors');

var routes = require('./server/routes.js');
var app = express();
var mongoOptions = { db: { safe: true }};
mongoOptions.user = database.user;
mongoOptions.pass = database.pass;

console.log('Running mongoose version %s', mongoose.version);

mongoose.connect(database.url, mongoOptions, function (err, res) {
  if (err) { 
    console.log ('ERROR connecting to: ' + database.url + '. ' + err);
  } else {
    console.log ('Successfully connected to: ' + database.url);
  }
});

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); 

app.use(logger('dev'));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(allowCors);

routes(app);

var server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('Express HTTP server listening on port ' .
        red + app.get('port'));
});

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error);

process.on('SIGINT', function() {
  db.close(function () {
    console.log('Mongoose default connection disconnected through app termination');
    process.exit(0);
  });
});
```

Alguém me ajuda? Estou a horas aqui e não resolvo o problema.
Já abri chamado para eles, porém vão responder só lá para segunda e gostaria de colocar minha aplicação para rodar antes.

Comment: Já correste `npm install`?...

Comment: Não é possível, a propria UOL faz isso na hora de subir a aplicação, as dependencias estão lá mas não funciona.